# Getting dates from an array

Tags: php

I found the following code from another post which gives me what I want except I would like to be able to grab each day as a variable so that I can use them in form fields.

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this?

```
<?php

$monday = new DateTime('monday');

// clone start date
$endDate = clone $monday;

// Add 7 days to start date
$endDate->modify('+7 days');

// Increase with an interval of one day
$dateInterval = new DateInterval('P1D');

$dateRange = new DatePeriod($monday, $dateInterval, $endDate);

foreach ($dateRange as $day) {
    echo $day->format('Y-m-d')."<br />";
}

?>
```

The results of the above are this:

2015-02-16

2015-02-17

2015-02-18

2015-02-19

2015-02-20

2015-02-21

2015-02-22

Many thanks,

John

Comment: I don't see any problems. You don't know how to wrap the result in HTML... ?

Comment: @Debflav no, I don't. I need to use the 7 dates as values in checkboxes. Can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$monday = new DateTime('monday');

// clone start date
$endDate = clone $monday;

// Add 7 days to start date
$endDate->modify('+7 days');

// Increase with an interval of one day
$dateInterval = new DateInterval('P1D');

$dateRange = new DatePeriod($monday, $dateInterval, $endDate);



foreach ($dateRange as $day) {

    echo "<input type='checkbox' value = {$day->format('Y-m-d')}>" . $day->format('Y-m-d')."<br />";

}
```

Comment: Yeah looks delicious!